# Binding data to Template Field in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to bind data to a templatefield in asp.net. I know you do this with the following code

```
Text = '<%#Bind("ColumnName") %>'
```

Where Text is the Text Property of the control I want to bind it to.
However I want to  bind a another thing to my text in the control, I want to bind to a Hyperlink's NavigateUrl the following:

```
"Default.aspx?id="
```

and bind this to and id from a database.
How can I achieve this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
NavigateUrl='<%# String.Format("Default.aspx?id={0}&nextParam={1}", Eval("ID"), Eval("NextColumn")) %>'
```

Comment: Other answers in this thread would work but this is the cleanest and my preferred way

Answer (score 1):

Try This.

```
 <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" NavigateUrl='<%# "~/Default.aspx?id=" + Eval("something") %>' runat="server">HyperLink</asp:HyperLink>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could have something like below:

```
NavigateUrl='<%# "Default.aspx?id=" +Eval("id") %>'
```